# What is the definition of $\min$, $\max$ of functions, $f_i$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a couple of questions:

1. What is the definition of the expressions on the right-hand side? Each $f_i : X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}_+}$
   $$
   h = \max(f_1, f_2, f_3,...f_n)
   $$
   $$
   h = \min(f_1, f_2, f_3,...f_n)
   $$
   The part which confuses me if that $f_i$ are functions, i.e. sequences of numbers, and not only an integer.
2. How can I determine the $\max$ and $\min$? Is it necessary to have a norm to determine the result?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,

Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this implicitly assumes $h(x)=\max\{f_1(x),...,f_n(x)\}$ (and likewise for $\min$).

You do not require norms, you simply let $h(x)$ take the largest value (or the smallest) at each $x$.

Comment: @MariusJonsson, to give an example, if $h(x)=\max\{-x,x\}$ for  $x\in[-1,1]$ then we get $h(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         x & \mbox{if $x \ge 0$};\\
        -x & \mbox{if $x \lt 0$}.\end{array} \right.=|x|$